# How to download message from an Exchange 2010 server in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server-2010

I just start a web application task to download messages from mailbox in an Exchange 2010 server for different users. Can someone give me a hint where to start? I use asp.net/c# programming. Any reference, article, sample or suggestion are highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for accessing Exchange 2010 is to use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx). See similar questions: [Access exchange e-mail in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865267/access-exchange-e-mail-in-c/6631276)
or 
[c# programmatically reading emails from the Exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249540/c-programmatically-reading-emails-from-the-exchange-server/5251780)