# Can't send or read emails with EWS in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exchangewebservices

I'm currently developing on a machine where it's not possible to debug.
 
At this point I'm trying to do some email related matters with my web application.

1. Send an email
2. Retrieve emails from functional mailbox

For some reason, both seem to be impossible to perform.
I wrote these blocks of code to see if I can get it up and running

The `SendEmails` function crashes on the `msg.Send()` part. I did a log on the `msg.ToRecipients.Address`, `msg.Subject` and the `msg.Body` and they are all filled in with the data I need.

The `GetEmailsFromFolder` function breaks as soon as it hits `FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(inbox, fView);`

```
public static ExchangeService CreateConnection()
{
    string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EWSAsmxUrlNp"];

    //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
    //    Object obj,
    //    X509Certificate certificate,
    //    X509Chain chain,
    //    SslPolicyErrors errors)
    //{
    //    return true;
    //};

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Url = new Uri(url);

    //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(@"DOM\User1", "password");

    return service;
}

public static void SendEmails(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    ExchangeService service = CreateConnection();

    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);
    msg.ToRecipients.Add(to);
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, body);
    msg.Send();
}

public static FindItemsResults<Item> GetEmailsFromFolder(Mailbox mailbox)
{
    ExchangeService service = CreateConnection();

    FolderView fView = new FolderView(100);
    fView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName);
    FolderId inbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox.ToString());
    FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(inbox, fView);

    return results;
}
```

I guess that in the `CreateConnection()` function the url is correct and working, because when I run it in the browser and after I enter my credentials I get the following XML returned: (only a small copy paste)

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema>
         <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" schemaLocation="messages.xsd"/>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="UploadItemsSoapIn">
      <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:UploadItems"/>
      <wsdl:part name="Impersonation" element="t:ExchangeImpersonation"/>
      <wsdl:part name="MailboxCulture" element="t:MailboxCulture"/>
      <wsdl:part name="RequestVersion" element="t:RequestServerVersion"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="UploadItemsSoapOut">
      <wsdl:part name="UploadItemsResult" element="tns:UploadItemsResponse"/>
      <wsdl:part name="ServerVersion" element="t:ServerVersionInfo"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   ... more here ...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Note 1: There is an Exchange server on a different location. Everybody logs in with their credentials and gets access to their account.**

**Note 2: With both crashes I get the following Exception (which I managed to log):**

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The
>   response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.
>   System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing. at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
>   at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read() at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read() at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType
>   nodeType) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadSoapFault(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException
>   webException) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest&
>   request) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable1
>   items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable1 messageDisposition,
>   Nullable1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId
>   parentFolderId, Nullable1 messageDisposition, Nullable1
>   sendInvitationsMode) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId
>   parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition) at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.Send() at
>   T.App.Factory.Helper.ExchangeWebServiceHelper.SendEmails(String to,
>   String subject, String body) in
>   D:\T.App\Factory\Helper\ExchangeWebServiceHelper.cs:line 77 at
>   PADAccountSwitching.App.Factory.NewBankFactory.DownloadRequests() in
>   D:\T.App\Factory\NewBankFactory.cs:line 313

Comment: It sounds like you are not hitting the service. This usually happens when a regular response (like a 404 HTML page) is being returned. I would suggest you somehow log what is being returned.

Comment: Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344400/exchange-web-services-the-response-received-from-the-service-didnt-contain-va

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exchange Web Services - The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344400/exchange-web-services-the-response-received-from-the-service-didnt-contain-va)

Comment: @Juan, I've read your answer and it probably has something to do with the XML. Could you perhaps tell me what value I specifically need to log to see what I get returned? Else this will take me quite a while to find what my XML looks like.

Comment: I usually use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to find root cause of issue.  Comparing results from a working location and a non working location will help find issue.  A good response should end with a status of 200 Done.  I would check your IE browser, firewalls and virus checkers to see if port or server is being blocked.

Comment: Check this out on how to log. Once we see the response from the server, it should be easier to figure out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: If you open a browser and go to https://mail.mydomain.com/ews/exchange.asmx what do you get? I'm referring to the 'service.Url' which you have set